# Quartz get the list of completed jobs

Tags: spring, triggers, quartz-scheduler

In Quartz version 2.2 how can we find if a job is finished and when?! I have the `job key` .

First I tried to get the job trigger and see the trigger status.

```
List<? extends Trigger> triggers = sched.getTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
for (Trigger trigger : triggers) {
   ....

}
```

But I find that quartz deletes the job trigger from database when the trigger finish successfully.

I googled an find http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/6791.page

> Quartz cleans up all of its own unused data so that an administrator
>   doesn't have to delete records filling up the database (many users
>   have millions of triggers firing repeatedly. it is impractical and
>   performance-hindering to keep all that data around).
>
> If you want a history of when triggers have fire, implement a
>   TriggerListener and record the info yourself, much as the
>   LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin does.
>
> Quartz 2.2 is likely to add a history feature with new api for
>   retrieving the data.

On the other hand I review the quartz code (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/Trigger.CompletedExecutionInstruction.html) and find that the trigger state can be set to `NOOP`, `RE_EXECUTE_JOB`, `SET_TRIGGER_COMPLETE`, `DELETE_TRIGGER`, `SET_ALL_JOB_TRIGGERS_COMPLETE`, `SET_TRIGGER_ERROR`, `SET_ALL_JOB_TRIGGERS_ERROR`

I think this enumeration is used for failed trigger, But I wonder if there is a way to make Trigger persist.

Comment: maybe you can use actuator, i see that there is some build in support for quartz https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#quartz